# Android/Java - How to access a variable declared in another file?

Tags: android, variables, global

I would like to know if it is possible to access a variable declared in another file.  For example:

```
httpPostFileUpload(client,
                   "/data/data/fshizzle.com/files/image.jpg",
                   "http://10.0.2.2/upload.php", "uploaded",
                   s.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Here, I'd like to replace `http://10.0.2.2/upload.php` with a URL stored in a variable, but with the variable declared in another file.  How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 4):

You can declare in another java file a public static variable which can then be accessed every where else.

For example,

Class1.java

```
package com.my.app;
public class Class1 {
    public static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/upload.php";
}
```

Class2.java

```
package com.my.app;
public class Class2 {
    public void Function(){
        httpPostFileUpload(client, "/data/data/fshizzle.com/files/image.jpg", 
                       Class1.URL, "uploaded", s.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
}
```

Class2 can see Class1 because both are in the same package (if they weren't, a simple `import Class1;` would fix this)

The `static` keyword means you can use the variable even without having access to an object of the specified class.

Finally, the `public` keyword allows you to access the variable from outside the class.